# What is Web Logic

Tags: weblogic, weblogic-10.x

I am looking for WebLogic 10.3 tutorial. and when i searched in net i could not find what is Web Logic 
why we have used

Please give me a simple explanation for `web logic` and tutorial to learn. I already tried to learn from  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15051_01/wls/docs103/intro/chap1.html#wp1127231 but i am  not clear on web logic

Comment: Google is your friend.

Comment: I already searched but not get clear explanation

Comment: It's an application server (web-container) like tomcat, glassfish and many others. Which means that it can serve both static as well as dynamic content (JSP pages for example).

Answer (score 2):

The author Frank Munz has an excellent book on WebLogic Oracle WebLogic Server Distinctive Recipes (Architecture, Development and Administration), for specific points.

If you're learning JavaEE , WebLogic is mostly a standard Java EE server, and many of the tutorials from equivalent software systems readily apply to WebLogic development in my experience. Look at widely-used app servers like Jetty or Tomcat, even WebSphere and you'll find there is a large StackOverflow community for supprt. For tutorials see for example DeveloperWorks http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/tutorials/j-tomcat/.

For tutorials about specifics of Weblogic,  is certainly the right place. ORACLE might assume you're using their 'Workshop for WebLogic 10.3' product http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13224_01/wlw/docs103/guide/introduction/conWorkshopTutorials.html
.

Could you elaborate a little about what level of tutorial you need?

Comment: i need tutorials about weblogic